# Clearing the data of another application

Tags: android

I'm writing an application that should be able clear the private data of any other application. If you're wondering about the use case, its along the lines of an MDM/MAM client. I'd like to selectively wipe application data (vs. a full device wipe).

I came across the following API call in the Android source code.

```
ActivityManager.clearApplicationUserData(String packageName,IPackageDataObserverobserver)
```

The odd part is, that this is not really available to you as part of the SDK . (So eclipse will give you hell for trying to use it). However, it **is** present (see [here](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.0_r1_src/index.html?android/app/ActivityManager.html)),you can invoke it via reflection. I'm still however, unable to get hold of the [IPackageDataObserver](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.0_r1_src/android/content/pm/IPackageDataObserver.html) interface.

Is there a better way of doing this? I know it CAN be done since I've seen products like MaaS360 do a selective wipe of applications' data.

Any suggestions?

---

### UPDATE

Based on what @lechlukasz has outlined below... the following code can execute...but you do finally land up with a SecurityException, since the package manager revokes the CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA permission when the app is installed.

```
Class<?> iPackageDataObserverClass= Class.forName("android.content.pm.IPackageDataObserver");

Class<ActivityManager> activityManagerClass=ActivityManager.class;
ActivityManager activityManager=(ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

Method clearDataMethod=activityManagerClass.getMethods()[0];

Object iPackageDataObserverObject = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
    MyApp.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[]{iPackageDataObserverClass}, 
                        new InvocationHandler() {

            public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) 
                    throws Throwable {
                Log.i("Proxy", method.getName() + ": " + Arrays.toString(args));
                return null;
            }
        });


clearDataMethod.invoke(activityManager, "com.example.test",iPackageDataObserverObject);
```

So this works, insofar as the method can be called. No luck on actually being able to clear the data itself. :-(

Comment: Does this MaaS360 work on non-rooted devices?

Comment: Yes it does. Infact that's the point. Enterprises deploy devices across their organization and can then remotely manage them. Stands to reason they don't want rooted devices.

Comment: This is propably the reason this API is not documented, since it needs root privileges to be called...

Comment: Erm. Okay. How else would you do it? MaaS360, just to be clear, does not need root. You cannot delete the files directly. The above API *can* be called. I've called it. I'm having problems with not having access to the above mentioned Interface, so I'm not able to pass a valid parameter for that. I've poked about the android source code a bit, I don't think it needs root.

Comment: But you can access class interface via reflection? You could try instantiating it via java.lang.reflect.Proxy

Comment: How do you do that? I cannot access the Interface, so can't get its Class object.

Comment: You can't get interface class via Class.forName? In that case, I have no idea :(

Comment: I can get the interface, but its exactly that, an interface. I cannot instantiate it. I cannot extend it. :(

Comment: To be clear, do you want to do this as a [device administrator](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html), or as a normal app?

Comment: Hii Archit iam getting illegalargumentexception expected 4 arguments but getting 2

Comment: @SoftwareSainath : I don't understand what you mean. For what method call are you getting an IllegalArgumentException? I'd suggest you post that as a separate question, with some code and a stack trace. That way someone actually may be able to help you out.

Comment: @Archit Thanks For Your Reply i'm getting error at  clearDataMethod.invoke(activityManager, "com.example.test",iPackageDataObserverObject);

Answer (score 2):

The method you point isn't static method, so in order to call it you would need the `ActivityManager` instance, which would be the trickiest part, even if you have root privileges. I can't help you with that.

But as for instantiating `IPackageDataObserver`, I've managed to do this without special privileges, using standard refrection API:

```
        Class ipdoClass = Class.forName("android.content.pm.IPackageDataObserver");
        Object observer = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                MyApp.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[]{ipdoClass}, 
                        new InvocationHandler() {

            public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) 
                    throws Throwable {
                Log.i("Proxy", method.getName() + ": " + Arrays.toString(args));
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Check out the edit above. I can finally invoke the method. No luck on it executing fully. You can get an instance of ActivityManager by calling getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, but you need to add appropriate permission in your manifest (CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA) and sign Your application with the platform key.

Comment: Yeah but that's a solution that does not really help much, since you then have to be writing an app that ships with the ROM itself.

Comment: It can be downloaded later, but the key needs to be the same.

Comment: My bad, I should clarify....for this to work (in the typical case) you  do have to be working with the hardware manufacturers. So if you are a third party developer...this approach is a dead end.

Comment: It would also be a security problem if an app that is not signed with the platform key would be able to do this